# Proof of Bode-Fano criterion

Tags: impedance-matching, bode-plot

I was reading [this thesis](https://repository.ntu.edu.sg/handle/10356/46759) and it mentions Bode-Fano criterion almost in every chapter of this thesis.

Could anyone advise about the [derivation of bode-fano criterion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jRR6.png)?

Note: The [original proof](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6329/517f5033428eb8ee5344f25ea02703ac00f9.pdf) is so tough to digest and comprehend.

[image: bode-fano criterion]

Comment: I don't fully understand what you need to prove? The idea is just that you integrate the reflection coefficient (which depends on frequency) over the bandwidth of interest, get an overall reflection coefficient. I think you need to look at the first paragraph of page 5! 
(by the way, I'm reading Fano's report and it's a treat to read, a little old-school, but very clear in how it leads me as the reader towards the conclusions. Maybe you just need to read it twice?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6329/517f5033428eb8ee5344f25ea02703ac00f9.pdf#page=5 ?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean with that comment. This is the report we're talking about, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller first paragraph of page 5 ??? Which document ?

Comment: There's only one document involved here. The Fano report, that you've linked to.

Comment: @kevin998x You should use https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6329/517f5033428eb8ee5344f25ea02703ac00f9.pdf#page=9 instead. (Note that Marcus was talking about page 5, as PRINTED on the page at the bottom. Not as indicated by the PDF viewer's perception. Different things.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Someone told me the following:  "The expression you pictured is the special case of an RC in parallel. 

It is derived by Bode in his book "Network Analysis and Feedback Amplifier Design": 
https://archive.org/details/NetworkAnalysisFeedbackAmplifierDesign/page/n1

His derivation starts in Chapter XVI, page 360 and that equation appears on page 367, equation (16-15).

It looks like he starts with the equation for mismatch loss in terms of the impedances and reflection coefficient in equation (16-10) and ends up with that equation two pages later."